# A Tour of Go Web Crawler: how is this channel being used concurrently?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm looking at this [mit solution](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/notes/crawler.go) to this [A Tour of Go exercise](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/10)

```
//
// Concurrent crawler with channels
//

func worker(url string, ch chan []string, fetcher Fetcher) {
    urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- []string{}
    } else {
        ch <- urls
    }
}

func coordinator(ch chan []string, fetcher Fetcher) {
    n := 1
    fetched := make(map[string]bool)
    for urls := range ch {
        for _, u := range urls {
            if fetched[u] == false {
                fetched[u] = true
                n += 1
                go worker(u, ch, fetcher)
            }
        }
        n -= 1
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}

func ConcurrentChannel(url string, fetcher Fetcher) {
    ch := make(chan []string)
    go func() {
        ch <- []string{url}
    }()
    coordinator(ch, fetcher)
}

func main() {
    //fmt.Printf("=== Serial===\n")
    //Serial("http://golang.org/", fetcher, make(map[string]bool))

    //fmt.Printf("=== ConcurrentMutex ===\n")
    //ConcurrentMutex("http://golang.org/", fetcher, makeState())

    fmt.Printf("=== ConcurrentChannel ===\n")
    ConcurrentChannel("http://golang.org/", fetcher)
}
```

What I don't understand is how this solution is concurrent? How is the use of this channel making the fetching of the urls parallel?

The way I see it is that, as you loop through the urls present on one 'page', you'll start a worker on any url that hasn't been 'fetched' yet.

But this worker just retrieves all the urls on the page it's being called on and puts this in the channel, so nothing seems to be happening in 'parallel'.

Rather it feels like urls are just getting placed into the channel page by page, and marked as 'fetched' iteratively

Comment: Channels don't make things parallel. What makes it parallel is this line: `go worker(u, ch, fetcher)`. Those will all execute concurrently.

Comment: @Adrian I thought the worker function would be executed rather instantaneously?

Comment: It's only instantaneous with the `FakeFetcher` in the example, which makes all concurrency in the example pointless - the whole app does nothing and takes no time. In a real version, `fetcher.Fetch` would make a network call, parse a response, build a list of URLs, etc. which would be far from instantaneous.

Comment: Stimulate a slow response time by adding a sleep before the fake fetcher call.   Then you can see it in action